# XPath in XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Using the following output XSD type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="MoneyType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
       <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I use a fn:sum command and get the following output:

```
1.0001865499999999E6
```

The value should be

```
1000186.55
```

What would cause this lack of precision

Thanks

Comment: because floating point numbers in computers are not precise?

Comment: E6 is scientific notation meaning * 10^6

Comment: All we know is that you might have an `xs:decimal`. You have not shared your input values to `fn:sum` with us, so how can we guess the problem?

Comment: @Jeremy Ah, didn't look all the way to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here:

(a) floating point arithmetic (or conversion of decimal values to floating point) causes approximation, because most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly in binary

(b) by default, numbers outside the range one-millionth to one million are output in "scientific notation", that is 2e6 rather than 2000000.

If you explain more carefully what you are doing and what you want to achieve then we can tell you how to avoid these problems.